# How to get currently allocation counts in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

I'm writing a memory manager in my project to manage Vulkan memory allocation. In practice, allocation counts should be smaller than `maxMemoryAllocationCount`, so I counted all allocations in my app, and check if it exceeds `maxMemoryAllocationCount` each allocation.

However, I think is design has bugs, because other apps could also allocate memories from the same device, so I need to get the allocation counts which are counted by the device, but I didn't find any kind of these APIs.

So do I miss something or `maxMemoryAllocationCount` are application local?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> other apps could also allocate memories from the same device

No, they cannot.

They can allocate memory from the same *physical* device. But they cannot allocate memory from the same `VkDevice` object. Such objects are specific to the process and cannot be shared. The allocations can be shared, but not the devices themselves (note that a shared allocation counts against the limit on all devices that can access it).

The specification is very clear that this is bound to a specific `VkDevice`:

> The maximum number of valid memory allocations that can exist simultaneously within a `VkDevice` may be restricted by implementation-or-platform-dependent limits. The `maxMemoryAllocationCount` feature describes the number of allocations that can exist simultaneously before encountering these internal limits.

When the specification says "device", unless it makes it clear otherwise, it means "`VkDevice`", not "actual GPU".